Javascript: Opening a new tab in mobile web (Android Chrome)
I am using the following javascript code to open a new tab in mobile web.
window.open("test.com", "_blank");

Unfortunately, it doesn't open a new tab. The navigation happens within the same tab. Can someone please help?
Device is Google Pixel 4a Android version 13
Mobile Browser Chrome 125.0.6422.113

Is this on a user interaction?

@mplungjan Yes it is
